# Добрый день помогите с Вопросом отправки сообщения PHP

Tags: php, sendmail

Добрый день пожалуйста  подскажите  мою ошибку .Сообщение никак не отправляется .В хостинге я посмотрел  функция для сообщение  включено. Можете подсказать где моя ошибка.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])){

  if(isset($carlist)){
           $carlist=$_POST['carlist'];

    switch($carlist){

           case 'jaguar': echo "Jaguar" ;break;
           case 'bmw': echo "bmw" ;break;
           case 'mercedes': echo "mercedes";break;
           default: echo"please choose your  car";
}
}




$to="may.maail77788899@gmail.com";
$subject="Car-Request";
$letter=$_POST['carlist'];

mail($to,$subject,$letter);

}




?>
```

Вот и HTML

```
 <form class="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">


    <select name="carlist">
       <option value=""

 name=""></option>
   <option value="jaguar">JAGUAR</option>
   <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
   <option value="mercedes">MERCEDES</option>

</select>



<button type="submit" id="carschoose" name="send">ORDER</button>

</form>
```

Comment: не знаю, у меня на тестовом сервере всё отправляется - что-то у вас с хостером всё-таки

Comment: Другое дело, что у вас какая-то непонятная проверка в коде - if(isset($carlist)). В момент проверки этой переменной ещё не существует, следовательно, проверка не проходит и echo не выводится. Но к отправке почты это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ .  Проблема  заключалась  в  хосте . Администрация   все решила .